# React: onLoad callback in img tag is not called

Tags: reactjs, image, onload, loader, preloader

How are they? Thank you for helping. I have it as the Keith solutions, but it still doesn't call the onLoad function. The only way for it to work and trigger onLoad is that instead of display, use visibility over the img parent tag. I would like it to work with display prop

if i do this the callback is triggered:

```js
function Test() {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const counter = useRef(0);
    const imageLoaded = () => {
        counter.current += 1;
        if (counter.current >= urls.length) {
            setLoading(false);
        }
}

return (
    <>
        <div style={{visibility: loading ? "visible" : "hidden"}}>
            Loading images...
        </div>
        <div style={{visibility: loading ? "hidden" : "visible"}}>
            {urls.map(url => 
                <img 
                    key={url}
                    src={url}
                    onLoad={imageLoaded}
                />
            )}
        </div>
    </>
)
```

but I want it to trigger with this:

```js
    <div style={{display: loading ? "block" : "none"}}>
       Loading images,
    </div>
    <div style={{display: loading ? "none" : "block"}}>
      {urls.map(url => 
            <img 
                key={url}
                src={url}
                onLoad={imageLoaded}
            />
        )}
    </div>
```

Comment: where is `urls` coming from and how do you set it?

Comment: I copied and pasted an example from a code to illustrate my problem. The problem as such is that if I have a parent with the display property of none, its child img does not trigger the onLoad function. It is that I am doing a preloader, and I would like the preloader to move before the images are loaded little by little. Ty!!